# Mobile version navigation 'undefined' on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, wordpress, undefined

This site is built on wordpress and when viewed with an iPhone 5, the title next to the navigation drop down just says 'undefined'.

I don't have an iPhone 5, so it's hard for me to test. My co worker has an older iPhone and it works fine. It also works on android and PC/Mac browsers when resized.

I tried googling for iPhone 5 issues with mobile sites, but couldn't find anything relevant. Does anyone have any information on this, or know a fix?

The site is: http://stage.fitn.com

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Working fine on iPhone simulator with 4 inch screen, which effectively has the same behavior as the real device. undefined text would be caused by wordpress backend setting rather then a frontend issue. Have you checked your navigation settings?

Comment: I tested it on an emulator and it worked fine for me as well. I guess it's not the navigation, but the text on the same line as the nav button. It's the 'site title' that's suppose to show next to the navigation, correct? The title is set on the back end.

Comment: above sidenav is title and then logo. It could be caused by browser cache but can't test it unless you have the device and hit refresh!

Comment: Someone next door has one and it came up as undefined. I made sure the title was set. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: screenshot? use Safari web inspector with the device connected to mac to see what inside the HTML content and debug from there.